# When I try to pass in the onPressed callback dynamically, he reports the following error

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_xc/util/color.dart';

class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final title;
  final bool enable;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const LoginButton(this.title,
      {Key? key, this.enable = true, required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: enable ? onPressed : null,
            color: primary,
            child: Text(title,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
            //shape  形态  RoundedRectangleBorder  长方圆形边框
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6))));
  }
}
```

An error is as follows：

The following assertion was thrown building LoginButton(dirty):
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Request an answer. Thank you.

Comment: try declaring enable variable as final bool? enable;

Comment: Can you show how you dynamically pass the callback?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final? title;
  final? bool enable;
  final? VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const LoginButton(this.title,
      {Key? key, this.enable = true, required this.onPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 1,
        child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed: enable ? onPressed : null,
            color: primary,
            child: Text(title,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
            //shape  形态  RoundedRectangleBorder  长方圆形边框
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6))));
  }
}
```